# Shared library loading and performance

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

I am writing a server side application in C/C++  which consists of 1 main daemon and several child processes.

I want the child processes to be extremely lightweight so that they can be spawned/killed without too much overhead (over and above that imposed by the OS).

I am building the main daemon and the children apps to make extensive use of shared libraries. In fact, the main daemon loads up all the shared libraries required by the child applications, and sets up the required (shared) memory structures etc.

My underlying assumption is that since the shared libraries (some of which are **huge**) are already loaded by the main daemon, the child applications will be able to launch quickly and simply attach to the loaded libraries - without having to load the shared libs, and thus resulting in a slightly fast time to be spawned - is this assumption correct?

**[[Added]]**

I am working on Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS

Comment: Are you working in a particular OS environment?  Your assumptions hold in the general case, but specific environments may require you to jump through some hoops to get this behaviour.

Comment: I think your assumption is correct, but can not find references to back up

Comment: @Gian: Please see my updated question. I am working on Linux

Comment: Also depends on how you're running those child processes. Fork or something else?

Comment: @Mat: I'm still in the design phase - so I am not committed to any particular method of launching the process. Whatever is more performant (as suggested and endorsed on here) is what I will implement.

Comment: I think there are several issues to consider:
1) Your libraries are huge -> So you can have Page-Swap!!
2) Are you using fork or vfork? ... or what?
3) How often do you spawn childs?
4) How many resources the childs will use?

Answer (score 1):

The code segment of your shared libraries will be shared by all processes, no particular restriction w.r.t who loaded/spawned. However, it may take variable time depending upon how many symbols are used in the process, as those will be resolved during load.

But if you are forking, there isn't much to do so it will be fast with respect to launching new binary.